# How to use Promise to return value from assync Angular function into calling method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have list which is filled in for cycle where I calling assync function by thos way:

**In For cycle I'm calling**

```
  row.SUCCES_RATE_SINCE = $scope.computeSuccessRateSinceStart(row);
```

**Called function**

```
  // Calculate percentage of a whole from since
    $scope.computeSuccessRateSinceStart = function(row) {

        db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:"callplanner"});
        // GET APPT COUNT
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql(sqlQuery, [], function(tx,results){
            // init empty array for results
            for (var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
                row = results.rows.item(i);
                //Udpate date for writeout
                //row.DATE = moment(row.DATE).format('ddd DD.M');
                console.log("row APPT count is " + JSON.stringify(row));
                apptCnt = row.APPT_CNT;
                convCnt = row.CONVERS_CNT;
                dailySuccessRateSince = apptCnt / convCnt * 100;
                console.log("Success rate since is " +dailySuccessRateSince);
                // THIS IS NOT WORKING
                return Math.round(dailySuccessRateSince);

            }
            });
        },function (e) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
                $ionicLoading.show({
                    template: $translate.instant('ERROR_DATABASE'),
                    duration:1000
                });
        });

    };
```

Problem is that computed value is always returned null (return function is executed before value is available in scope).

I'm quite new in Angular but i found that this issue could be solved using **promises**. Could somebody give me the example how to return value properly?

Many thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

Called method is now triggered, but i cannot pass returned value into variable like this:

```
var test = $scope.computeSuccessRateSinceStart(row).then(function(result){
     //ALERT WITH VALUE WORKS FINE
     alert("Result " + result);
     return result;
    });
    // THIS GIVES ME EMPTY ARRAY {}
    alert("Result " + JSON.stringify(test));
```

Comment: Not even promises allow you to return the value - it still would be asynchronous. You could return a *promise for the value*, though.

Comment: Could You please add some example based on my code? I tried a few tutorials but without luck.

Comment: Mohammad's answer covers it quite well (I've edited it for a bit clarity). And **NO**, it is outright **impossible** to pass the "returned value" into a variable, because your code is *asynchronous*. Do everything in the callback!

Comment: Could You add some example of "Do Everything in callback" please? Because in for cycle are called some other functions which are assync too.

Comment: What for cycle? Yes, make that loop a recursive function and call the next step from the callback.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just make your method such that it always returns a promise, and then extract the result from the promise?

```
$scope.computeSuccessRateSinceStart = function(row) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:"callplanner"});
    // GET APPT COUNT
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql(sqlQuery, [], function(tx,results){
            // init empty array for results
            for (var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
                row = results.rows.item(i);
                //Udpate date for writeout
                //row.DATE = moment(row.DATE).format('ddd DD.M');
                console.log("row APPT count is " + JSON.stringify(row));
                apptCnt = row.APPT_CNT;
                convCnt = row.CONVERS_CNT;
                dailySuccessRateSince = apptCnt / convCnt * 100;
                console.log("Success rate since is " +dailySuccessRateSince);
                // THIS IS NOW WORKING:
                deferred.resolve(Math.round(dailySuccessRateSince));
            }
        });
    }, function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
        deferred.reject(e);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Usage:

```
$scope.computeSuccessRateSinceStart(row).then(function(result){
    // THIS GIVES THE VALUE:
    alert("Result " + JSON.stringify(test));
    return result;
}, function(e) 
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: $translate.instant('ERROR_DATABASE'),
        duration:1000
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it intentional that you didn't fix the problem in your code?

Comment: If you mean the line below:`// THIS IS CALLED WHEN DATA ARE NOT AVAILABLE` Where The promise is being resolved regardless of what happened before it, Yes. I thought it's not relevant to the main issue of handling async tasks, but yea, that line shouldn't be there.

Comment: @redrom The idea is to return a promise or a callback if you're performing an async task. Tbh I don't know how many async calls there are in the code you posted, Try the code in my answer now, I removed that problematic line Bergi mentioned.

Comment: Seems to be triggered right now, but i still cannot pass returned value into variable, please see my updated question.